# How can I set my variable in windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I used this script:

```
rem @echo off
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
Set crs=
REM Get the result from sl.txt
FIND "LISTENER_SCAN1" <sl.txt >sl_temp_01.txt
FIND "running" <sl_temp_01.txt >sl_final.txt
DEL sl_temp_01.txt
for /F "tokens=8 delims= " %%j in (sl_final.txt) do (
IF %%J EQU "40" (SET crs=crs1)
IF %%J EQU "41" (SET crs=crs2)
IF %%J EQU "42" (SET crs=crs3)
IF %%J EQU "43" (SET crs=crs4)
Echo %%j
Echo !crs!
Pause
)
```

I can get echo %%j as 42 this time, but I cannot set my variable crs as crs3.
Could you please help?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If `%%J` already contained enclosing double quotes your if could be
  valid,   if not this is never true.
- To be sure use the `~` modifier to strip possible double quotes and
  set them yourself.

---

```
IF "%%~J" EQU "40" (SET crs=crs1)
```

- Also `%%J` and `%%j` are distinct meta variables - in your batch you
  use them once in lowercase and then uppercase.
- If variables are possibly empty put a different command separator
  behind  the echo `(=` for example - not a space. This would return
  `echo is on/off` then.
- There is no need for intermediate files, stack two find commands and
  parse the output with the `for /f`

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\27\SO_51067292.cmd
@echo off & SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
Set "crs="

for /F "tokens=8 delims= " %%J in (
    'FIND "LISTENER_SCAN1" ^<sl.txt ^| FIND "running"'
) do (
    IF "%%~J" EQU "40" (SET crs=crs1)
    IF "%%~J" EQU "41" (SET crs=crs2)
    IF "%%~J" EQU "42" (SET crs=crs3)
    IF "%%~J" EQU "43" (SET crs=crs4)
    Echo=%%J
    Echo=!crs!
    Pause
)
```